# Can't connect to ODBC database with pyodbc. Which SQL Server driver should I install on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, python

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server database using a python script. I'm using the pyodbc library to connect to it.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Driver}; SERVER=192.168.80.30 ;DATABASE=users;UID=data;PWD=xxxx')
```

When running the script with the above connection configuration I get:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

It seems that I don't have the SQLDriver installed. Doing some research I haven't found a driver that works. Which ODBC driver should I install on the Raspberry Pi? I'm using Raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/docs.html) or for [pymssql](http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/). From pymssql docs:

> A simple database interface for Python that builds on top of FreeTDS to provide a Python DB-API (PEP-249) interface to Microsoft SQL Server.